# Spread Syntax in Plugin not working in IE/edge

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babeljs, spread-syntax

I have a plugin (react-form-with-constraints) in my react app (started with create-react-app and ejected). As this plugin uses spread syntax it doesn't work in IE and Edge. The error Edge gives:

> SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

I know I need to use babel to transpile the code, and have added the path to the plugin to webpack.config.js:

```
test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: [paths.appSrc, path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-form-with-constraints")],
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
```

The relevant portions of package.json:

```
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
"babel-loader": "8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.0",
```

and

```
 "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "include": [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5"
  }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something and probably done something else wrong, but this being my first time using react, I am fairly lost and looking for advice.

Comment: Which version of IE/Microsoft Edge version are you using? Before using the plugin whether your reactjs application works well in IE and Edge browser?

Answer (score 1):

Create-react-app doesn't support IE11 out of the box. You will need to add react-app-polyfill for that.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax),

`Spread syntax` is not supported in `IE`/`Edge`. All other morder browser's are supported.

[image]

In `Edge v12`, `Spread in array literals` & `Spread in function calls` are **Supported** only `Spread in destructuring` & `Spread in object literals` are **NOT Supported**.